# Post answer to incomplete question that already solved in comments

Tags: discussion

My question is about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848632/term-does-not-evaluate-to-a-function-taking-0-arguments/49849767?noredirect=1#comment86715003_49849767) question on SO.

The mentioned question is incomplete and you can't answer it until you see the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So someone trying to help by guessing the problem in the comment section.

You get lucky and fortunately your guess is correct and now OP's problem is solved. After this almost any new user will not edit their answer since the problem is solved and their unlikely to get back in any short while.

After this situation (maybe a day later) someone come and investigate the comments and post it as answer (not even try to expand it a bit more).

***My question is that is this kind of behaviour is OK?*** As mentioned in the comments of the answer I know answers should not be posted as comment but there was no answer, just blindly guesses and the question remained the same and it's still not complete and can't be answered.

You may say that question clarified at comments so it's OK now, but after a while, if someone see this problem he/she might not read the comments and question is still wrong but the answer looks OK.

---

About duplicate link, I read it before posting this question and as I mentioned I know answers should not post as comments and after that anyone can use them and answer the question and it's OK.

My question is about doing so when a question **can't** be answered. Maybe the example I provided isn't big enough but I saw this kind of behaviour many times.

Comment: I guess the OP already forget the question since he got what he need and will never come back ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif indeed. but I'm asking about posting answer to this questions.

Comment: Posting an answer to this question is wrong regardless whether or not it was resolved in comments. It should be closed/not answered because it lacks MCVE.

Comment: I would say there is nothing against doing such thing but I think that before answering you need to check comments and previous answers before. So answering blindly is not a good behavior.

Comment: The way I see it.. there are two things here:1. the original question lacks MCVE and 2. a user took an answer from the comment and posted it. If we dont consider the first and only 2nd point, they should have credited the user who posted the comment in their answer.

Comment: Or they could have posted as community wiki in order to have an answer there. Comments are ephemeral in this site

Comment: As I saw in the comment section of the answer this kind of attitude is kind of supported, Because my protest caused an upvote to the answer :)

Comment: Hans was the last one to "solve" it ...

Comment: One definitely shouldn't post answers to off-topic questions. That just makes it harder to get them deleted. This might also be the reason why the answer was in a comment.

Comment: @BDL exactly. This is what I'm talking about.